# Where to find the message templates from Exception when testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR and testing. There is a conundrum when it comes to testing. I don't know what error messages returned from the default Exceptions such as ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, so I can't simply test using

```
expect(response.body).to match()
```

Where to find those message templates? The official API website is kind of useless in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using RSPEC you can try something like this

`get(:action) { post :my_test, params: { 'event': 'testing' } }`

`it { expect { action }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound }`

This site will help you with tests http://betterspecs.org